# Periodic boundary for 3D sphere packing

Tags: graphics

I have the $x,y,z$ coordinates and radius $r$, of $N$ spherical particles, packed in a box with size $L$. For some cases, $x \pm r$ and/or $y\pm r$ and/or $z\pm r$ go outside the box. I want to be able to wrap them around so that the fraction of the sphere not outside the box shows on the other side. Second, I want to be able to turn this into a binary matrix of $N \times N \times N$ with zeros and ones representing void and solid pixels. I know for the first part I have to use `Mod[]` but can't figure out how. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: And what have you tried? How are "pixels" related to spheres?

Comment: The pixels - or i should have said voxels - come into picture when putting the system on a lattice. That's of a secondary importance. In terms of the wrapping the fraction of sphere that goes out of the box in  - i tried identifying that bounded region and moving it by \pm L depending on where it goes out MATLAB. However that approach seems to get too messy too soon. I prefer working with Mathematica and thought there might be a more efficient approach on this platform.

Comment: So please show us your code

Comment: Do you know how to do it in 2D? Try there first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D is the same as 2D so for simplicity I stick to 2D.

First part: plot the position vector shifted 2L in each direction, inefficient but it works.

```
L = 10;
pos = RandomInteger[{-L, L}, {10, 2}]
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[White], 
   Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}]}], 
 Table[Graphics[
   MapIndexed[{Hue[#2/10], Disk[#1 + {2 i L, 2 j L}]} &, 
    pos]], {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, {-L, L}}]
```

[image]

Second part: take the `Floor` of the position and put a square on it.

```
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[White], 
   Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}]}], 
 Table[Graphics[
   MapIndexed[{Black, Rectangle[Floor[#1] + {2 i L, 2 j L}]} &, 
    pos]], {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, {-L, L}}]
```

[image]

Here there's no need to plot the shifted data since `Floor` takes care of putting the particles inside the box.

And a gratuitous gif:

[image]

full disclusure: my phd was on particle simulation so I developed a love for moving colorful dots. You can make really cool flipbooks with this.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think OP required the new box to enclose the the spheres. So that none of them are cut off by the box. Also the 3D matrix part could be tricky?

Comment: "I want to be able to wrap them around so the fraction of the sphere not outside of the box shows on the other size." I understood this as he wants half spheres if they are beyond the borders, like orange and pink. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: @MathX in what sense the 3D matrix can be tricky? memory wise and such? I don't see any problem on going to 3D.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa Smart using of `PlotRange`instead of `RegionIntersection` etc... It looks like the interest towards "boxed" questions is high now days.

Comment: @BlacKow it was mas first thought, to region difference with some band on the borders, but that would have been too complicated if you are only interested on seeing them

Comment: @tsuresuregusa I tried using region RegionIntersection in 3D and gave up, too much work

Comment: @tsuresuregusa  see, that might be the reason he asked the question in the first place. He hasn't shown a code so maybe he tried that.

Comment: Thanks you all. The gif is awesome! This is much more efficient that what i did - essentially the brute force method by manually adding mirror structures around all six faces of my cubic cell and using PlotRange. Also working on my PhD with some particle simulations involved - colors should make for great presentations :)

Comment: if you are using hue for kinetic energy or such, remember that the color is red for both 0 and 1. And please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.